# The Mathematical Puzzle That Is So Mathematical It Will Blow Mathematical Minds Of Mathematics Away!

Tags: number-sequence

> **Here is a short sequence that I made when brainstorming puzzles:**
>
> ```
> 19
>
> 101
>
> 920
>
> 20009
>
> 701
>
> 104
>
> 403
>
> 311
>
> 3000000000000000003
>
> ...
> ```
>
> **You need to figure the next one out.**

*Just so you know, this is an actual series that I made, and although the jump to 3,000,000,000,000,000,003 is ridiculous, it will make sense when you see the answer.*

**EDIT**: It has come to my attention that 14004 would be a better substitute for 3000000000000000003. I am going to leave 3000000000000000003 on the chart as it would also be a feasible answer.

Answer (score 3):

This could relate to

> The number of digits in really large powers of ten with names....

19

> There are 19 digits in $10^{18}$, a quintillion (in North America).

101

> There are 101 digits in $10^{100}$, a googol.

920

> 

20009

701

104

403

311

> 

3000000000000000004

> There are this many digits in an [attillion](https://googology.wikia.org/wiki/Attillion)

Comment: Sadly, this is on the wrong track...

Comment: Darn, I thought the 3000000000000004 one was perfect! Thanks though @XDVV

Comment: I'm actually very surprised you managed to find 3000000000000000004 useful for anything!